# How to remove the old fragment from the fragment itself

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am invoking a fragment(GetStartFragment) from an activity(DiscoverActivity) and from the same fragment (GetStartFragment), I am replacing it with another fragment (SelectFragment). Now I need to remove the old fragment (GetStartFragment) when I perform onClick() method as below.  I was trying to remove, but the fragment ID returns null. How to remove the old fragment from the fragment itself.

**DiscoverActivity.java :**

```
public class DiscoverActivity implements AppCompatActivity {

.....
 case R.id.start:
         showGetStartFragment();
         return true;

 .....

    private void showGetStartFragment() {
        lGetStartFragment = GetStartFragment.newInstance();
        lGetStartFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), lGetStartFragment.getTag());
    }
}

**FragmentDiscover.java :** 

public class GetStartFragment extends BaseBottomSheetDialogFragment {

   public static GetStartFragment newInstance() {
        return new GetStartFragment();
    }
    .....

    @OnClick(R2.id.getstart_button)
        void onGetStartButtonClick() {
            boolean isStart = true;
            /* Show Fragment 2 */
            SelectFragment lSelectFragment = SelectFragment.newInstance();
            SelectFragment.show(requireActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), SelectFragment.getTag());

            /*Remove previous fragment - Fragment 1*/
            FragmentManager fm = requireActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            Fragment fragment_ID = fm.findFragmentById(com.misc.exam.R.id.design_getstart);
            FragmentTransaction fmt = fm.beginTransaction();
            if (fragment_ID != null) {
                fmt.remove(fragment_ID).commitAllowingStateLoss();
            }
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            FragmentManager fm = requireActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            Fragment fragID = fm.findFragmentById(com.misc.exam.R.id.design_getting_started);
            FragmentTransaction fmt = fm.beginTransaction();
            if (fragID != null) {
                fmt.remove(fragID).commitAllowingStateLoss();
            }
        }
       ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried saving the current fragment in a separate field and replacing it?

```
Fragment currentFragment;
currentFragment = new NewFragment()
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,currentFragment)
```

Comment: Thanks. I have tried this, but I still see the old fragment when I press the back button. Though I have set .addBackStack(null) in the fragmentTransaction.

Comment: Ah ok, i understand
So now it works with _.addToBackstack(null)_ ?